# Implementation of placeholder tokens

Tags: swift, swift-playground

It seems that the [standard Apple implementation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_playgrounds/specifying_editable_regions_in_a_playground_page) of the Placeholder Tokens (to show a custom slider popover for integer values) for Playground Books just doesn't work.

Pasting Apple's code results in this, in Xcode:

```
var typedLlamaCount = /*#-editable-code*/<#T##number of llamas##Int#>/*#-end-editable-code*/
```

[image: Xcode? What?]

Has anybody ever succeeded in doing this? Is it a functionality for which has been provided documentation but hasn't been released yet? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like documentation for iOS application Swift Playground, not Playground in Xcode.

Comment: Of course, once compiled the code would be executed on an iPad.